# What type of button is this?

Tags: html, css, frontend

What type of button is being used in this picture?
[image]
I've been trying to replicate the result shown in this image by using radio buttons (so only one can be selected) but I've been struggling a lot to make the radio buttons both square and contain text.
So far my buttons at best look like this:
[image]

Are there any simple ways of achieving the first result shown?

(Link for button I'm trying to replicate: https://www.poppyraffle.org.uk/?seg=WFMWEBPPC&gclid=Cj0KCQjwlN32BRCCARIsADZ-J4ugFDkJWk0d_x_pLSIfm6TY_jiLEilxDN99-vzeIIOg3Ls5lHv6Rm4aAljPEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: where you got this button example give link

Comment: @aviboy2006 thanks i've added it in

Comment: Just inspect the element through the browser development tools. It will tell you everything you want to know.

Comment: Don’t use squares to indicate radio buttons.

Comment: A brief inspection of the DOM on that link shows that the actual radio buttons are not visible and these are styled `<li>` elements and such.  There is also JavaScript involved to connect the visible elements to the form elements.

Comment: @Zze I've been trying to copy what they did but so far nothing's working

Comment: added solution. only selected value logic is not there. @Umber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added same styling except selection value logic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".tickets-button").click(function() {
    $(".tickets-button").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

  });

});
```

```css
.tickets-wrapper {
  background-color: #838383;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 66%
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .ticket-buttons-wrapper {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .ticket-buttons-wrapper {
  
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.ticket-buttons-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 12%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) #tickets .tickets-button {
  width: 19%;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.ticket-buttons-wrapper .tickets-button {
  float: left;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tickets-button [type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

#tickets .tickets-button label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.tickets-button.active {
  background-color: #e00a0f;
  color: #ffffff;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.other-amount .tickets-text {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="tickets-wrapper">
    <div class="ticket-buttons-wrapper">
      <ul>

        <li class="tickets-button predef-values active">
          <input type="radio" name="entries" value="15" id="tickets-15">
          <label for="tickets-15">15</label>
        </li>

        <li class="tickets-button predef-values">
          <input type="radio" name="entries" value="10" id="tickets-10" checked="checked">
          <label for="tickets-10">10</label>
        </li>

        <li class="tickets-button predef-values">
          <input type="radio" name="entries" value="5" id="tickets-5">
          <label for="tickets-5">5</label>
        </li>

        <li class="tickets-button other-amount">
          <input type="radio" name="entries" value="Other" id="tickets-other">
          <label for="tickets-other">other</label>
          <input type="text" class="tickets-text" name="other-amount" placeholder="max 20 tickets" value="">
          <script type="text/javascript">
            var valueMaxTicket = '20';
          </script>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```